# ./vish: error while loading shared libraries: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04, I installed modelsim while running I am getting this error.

> ./vish: error while loading shared libraries: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  It's possible you are missing this library https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxext-dev  (so an `sudo apt install libxext-dev` will fix)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you are missing this library https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libXext

Install withFix with

`sudo apt install libxext-dev`